# Nginx reverse-proxy and root problem in multiple websites

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have an IP address of my server that I want to put my website Frontend and Backend admin. The site1 part is simply should be at "http://IP/" and and site2 should be in "http://IP/admin" .

I have installed Nginx in server and my websites files are inside: Lets say its like :

```
site1: /var/www/html/site1/index.html
site2: /var/www/html/site2/index.html
```

I created 2 files in /etc/nginx/site-available/ called "site1.conf" and "site2.conf" .

site1.conf:

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

 root /var/www/html/site1;                                       
 index index.html index.htm;                                

 server_name http://myIP;                         

 location / {                                               

     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;                         
 } 
}
```

site2.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
 server_name http://myIP;       

 location /admin {                      
 autoindex on;                          
 alias /var/www/html/site2;             
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html last; 
 index index.html;                      
 }
}
```

Then I linked these 2 files into "/etc/nginx/site-enabled"

After restarting the Nginx, my "http://ip/" opens site1 "index.html" and works fine.

but "http://ip/admin/" gives 404 error instead of opening site2 "index.html"

Answer (score 0):

`http://IP/` and `http://IP/admin` both point to the same server, with the `server_name` "IP".

Your server contains at least two `location` blocks.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;

    root /var/www/html/site1;                                       
    index index.html index.htm;                                

    location / {                                               
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;                         
    }

    location /admin {                      
        alias /var/www/html/site2;             

        ...
    }
}
```

The server name only contains the text of the IP address or the DNS name. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

---

You can spread your configuration across as many files as you choose. See [the `include` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include).

The `nginx` configuration is a file called `nginx.conf` and contains an `include` statement to source all of the files in the `sites-available` directory. The content of these files are contained within the `http { ... }`.

As I have already stated, your two services are one `server { ... }` block, as far as `nginx` is concerned. However, you can still create a `server` block file in `sites-available` that includes files from some other location. Just don't use `sites-avalable` or `conf.d`, as `nginx` is aready using those directory names.

For example:

In `sites-available/mysites.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;

    include /path/to/my/location/confs/*.conf;
}
```

And in `/path/to/my/location/confs/site1.conf`:

```
root /var/www/html/site1;                                       
index index.html index.htm;                                

location / {                                               
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;                         
}
```

And in `/path/to/my/location/confs/site2.conf`:

```
location /admin {                      
    alias /var/www/html/site2;             

    ...
}
```

I am not saying that this is a good way to organise your files, but with `nginx`, many things are possible.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I can fix these two inside one conf. But I want each website to have one conf file. Would it be possible?

Comment: I have already stated that it works when you put 2 locations inside the same conf file. But imagine that I have different domain names for "http://IP" and "http://IP/admin". That is why I want to put each one in 1 server to give different domain names. I think I can not explain my problem.

Comment: The point is that Ip/admin is not a different domain. It is the same domain with a different location and nginx will always process it within the same server block.